# Is it safe to serialize a float in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, serialization, floating-point

I'm serializing Python `float`s to a CSV file via

```
import csv

some_float = 3 / 5
csv.writerow([..., some_float, ...])
```

and then reading them back via `pandas.read_csv` as `np.float64`. Is it guaranteed that the floating-point value I read in will be the value I get out, or is it possible that I may lose some precision? Thanks.

Comment: Why do not you save it as bytes? Then you will not lose precision.

Comment: @eyllanesc Well, *can* I lose precision if I save is as text? That is the question.

Comment: I think that precision is lost, since to save a floating number in a CSV it is saved as text, so they will have to place a limited number of decimals, but floats can have a large number of decimals.

Comment: The details of Python's `float` type are [implementation-dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric).

Comment: @chepner I'm talking about the 99% case; it's safe to assume the implementation is CPython.

Comment: Even with CPython, it depends on what the underlying C libraries provide. "Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C; information about the precision and internal representation of floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is running is available in sys.float_info."

Comment: @eyllanesc Well the `csv` module seems to serialize an awful lot of decimals, most of the values I'm getting for example have ~10 decimal places.

Comment: @chepner Still asking about the 99% :) `double` has been the standard for implementing floating-point numbers for a long time.

Comment: a floating number of 64 bits can have more than 10 decimals, why do you want to use a CSV? Why do not you use HDF5?

Comment: @JamesKo You're asking if you are guaranteed to not lose precision; the answer to that question is "no".

Comment: Definitely no, why you ask this question but not just have a try? I can give an example in one second `3/7` `2 ** 0.5`... and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment in the Python source suggests this is safe.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L828

`/* The repr() precision (17 significant decimal digits) is the
   minimal number that is guaranteed to have enough precision
   so that if the number is read back in the exact same binary
   value is recreated.  This is true for IEEE floating point
   by design, and also happens to work for all other modern
   hardware. */`

Double check you are getting up to 17 significant digits in your csv file - otherwise you may need to force convert your floating point numbers with repr() on output to csv.